# Need SQLite to replace only rows with new information

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am making an SQLite database that is going to store information from a webserver(for an android app) that had data that may change at any time. It seems inefficient to me to delete the table and re-make the table.

Is there a way of detecting change? For example, a VehicleID won't change so how can I check to see if a row changed or whatever?

My current implementation which I don't like

```
public int updateAllVehicle(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    // vehicleList populated? Basically to see that I am not going to lose my list of vehicles
    if (vehicleList.size() * .75 > getVehicleCount()) {
        //delete table
        db.delete(TABLE_VEHICLE, null, null);
        //remake table
        for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicleList) {
            values.put(KEY_VEHICLE_ID, vehicle.getvehicleID());
            values.put(KEY_TRACK_ID, vehicle.gettrackID());
            values.put(KEY_VEHICLE_NAME, vehicle.getvehicleName());
            ...(20 more attributes here that I omitted for StackOverflow)
        }

        return vehicleList.size();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Update: I am getting a full table's worth of information but it's possible that any number of rows are updated

Comment: is the ENTIRE table being updated, or just certain rows?

Comment: I am getting a full table's worth of information but it's possible that any number of rows are updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to solve that with these steps:

- Create a convenience-method `isTechnicalEqual(Vehicle pVehicle)` in `Vehicle` which compares all attributes except the ID attribute:

  ```
          //Dont forgett Nullcheck!
          if (!this.gettrackID().equals(pVehicle.gettrackID()))
          return false;
          //etc... after all attribute are checked:
          return true;
  ```

  If one attribute is not equal `return false`. At the end of the function `return true`.
- Now select all existing Vehicle's from your local database and store it in a `Map<Integer,Vehicle>` lLocalDb //The Integer is your Vehicle-ID
- Create two Lists: `List<Vehicle>` for Vehicle's which must be inserted and another one for the updates.
- Iterate over all passed Vehicle's and call:

  ```
      Vehicle lVehicleDB = lLocalDb.get(lVehicle.getId());
      if (null == lVehicleDB){
        lInsertList.add(lVehicleDB);
      }else{
        if (!lVehicleDB.isTechnicalEqual(lVehicle))
          lUpdateList.add(lVehicle);
      }
  ```
- After the loop is finished do the following stuff:

  ```
      if (!lInsertList.isEmpty){
        //Call SQLite insert for the list lInsertList
      }
      if (!lUpdateList.isEmpty){
        // Call SQLite update for the list lUpdateList
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to make use of functionality built into the framework named "Loaders" (introduced in API 3.0).  This will automatically update the dataset backing your list, and provide updates to the UI (which you can act upon when you want).

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

If you are using a ViewHolder in your adapter, if data updates in your list (but isn't appearing on the screen), the dataset will be updated, but the user won't be effected (until they scroll to the new data, which will be there).

I think you should make use of this built-in functionality, instead of using a custom approach (as this should be more extensible).

Comment: ah, yes loaders. I have faintly read about these.

So I currently have an AsyncTask that returns a HashMap<Vehicle> from an XML file sent to me by a HTTP POST. 

Do i add the loader to what I have or is it isntead of some portion?