# Check SQLite database for duplicate entries, CursorLoader/Loader/AsyncTaskLoader? Confusion

Tags: android, sqlite

As I posted here [Need SQLite to replace only rows with new information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323000/need-sqlite-to-replace-only-rows-with-new-information), I need to get information from a webserver and compare it with what I have in my SQLite database. (Android App)

I currently have an AsyncTask implemented that gives me a HashMap. 
I was in the process of coding an SQLite database when I came across Loaders.

I am confused about how to do this.

Do I want to use CursorLoader or AsyncTaskLoader in this case? Do I replace the current AsyncTask subclass that I have now?

```
private class getFleetList extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Vehicle>>> {

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, ArrayList<Vehicle>> doInBackground(
                String... params) {
               //...implemented AsyncTask
            }
```

My current guess is that I will replace my AsyncTask. A tutorial link or something would be very helpful. All tutorials that I have found use broadcast receivers or post to ListViews and that is not what I am doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask runs code on a non-UI (usually called a "background") thread. An AsyncTask can do anything, but it's a bit fragile because it disappears if the system restarts the Activity that started the AsyncTask. This can happen quite easily, because the system restarts the current Activity if the user rotates the device (unless you trap onSystemConfigurationChanged).

Formally, an AsyncTaskLoader is a Loader that uses AsyncTask to run its code. This means in real terms that an AsyncTaskLoader gets data from somewhere by using a non-UI thread (the AsyncTask part). The loader part just gives you convenience methods for dealing with the process of getting data, which may take a long time. The loader part also lets you track the data and restart the load if the data changes.

Based on what you've said, your current implementation can use either AsyncTask or AsyncTaskLoader. If you need the features of Loader, choose AsyncTaskLoader; otherwise, stick with AsyncTask.

You can't use CursorLoader. Although it's not immediately obvious, you need a content URI to create a CursorLoader, which means you need a content provider. In your situation, there's no obvious advantage in using a CursorLoader. A CursorLoader adds stuff on top of AsyncTaskLoader, such as a built-in ContentObserver that automatically triggers reloads when data for the original CursorLoader query's content URI changes.

Basically, you're just looking at layers of class definition that add functionality for more and more specific situations.

Having said all this, I see that you want to ensure that a web server's database and the device's database are always "in sync". Correct?

You can always tell when a row has changed in a content provider, because you can register a ContentObserver for the provider. When something in an app tries to mutate the data being "observed", you get a callback. The system detects the mutation by comparing the URI passed to the ContentResolver call to the URI you register to observe. Unfortunately, you can't do this for an SQLite database.

If data on the web server changes, you can notify a device using Google Cloud Messaging.

In both cases, you can create a sync adapter to handle the data transfer and synchronization tasks, and run it when the data changes.

The tricky part is deciding how to handle conflicts, but you're only looking for updates and additions (and deletions?).

Comment: Internet man, so good. Thanks for responding, I thought this wasn't going to get an answer!
Yes, I have already experienced the fragility(?) of AsyncTask when I rotate my device. 

So why would I want to use a loader? Android Dev: "They monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the content changes."

I think this is probably the reason I want loaders. I could simply update the entire SQLite database everytime (about 1000 objects) or I could somehow detect changes(http://stackoverflow.com/a/17323515/2482818 I got this suggestion but is it too inflexible?)

Comment: Also, What is a sync adapter?

I have an AsyncTask already implemented, does that mean that if I want AsyncTaskLoader i have to reimplent everything?

Thanks a ton, your answer really helps a new developer understand !